# How can I perform a selector when the user hits the Send button on the iPhone keyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have a UITextView. When the user hits the Send key I want to be able to automatically perform a selector. How can I do this? I know UITextField has

`- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this out:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
 replacementText:(NSString *)text; {
  // Any new character added is passed in as the "text" parameter.
  if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
    // If the Done button was pressed, resign the keyboard.
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    // Return FALSE so that the final '\n' character doesn't get added.
    return NO;
  }
  // For any other character return TRUE so that the text gets added to the view.
  return YES;
}
```

Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
[self performSelector:@selector(aMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

in

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView 
{
  return YES;
}
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: I have a UITextView. the delegate method you proposed is for a UITextField which is different.